# Echo output in color

Tags: batch

I want to have the output of below For /f function in RED color but it does not work out. What is the easily way to do it.

```
for /f %%i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do  @echo %ESC%[91m%%i%ESC%[0m && set result=%%i
```

REVISION-2

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

for /f %%i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (
    call :colorEcho 06 "%%i" 
    set result=%%i
)


:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~
```

2" > nul 2>&1

ERROR[image]

REVISION 3

Get active connected MAC address

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

for /f "skip=2 delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4" %%L in ('wmic nic where "netenabled=true" get macaddress^,index^,netconnectionid^,productname /format:csv') do @for /f "skip=2 delims={}, tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic nicconfig where "index=%%M" get ipaddress^,ipsubnet ^/format:csv') do (
echo %%N
set result=%%N
)
call :colorEcho 06 %result%
goto end


:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1


:end
pause
exit
```

[image]

Comment: What OS do you use? This doesn't look like any classic POSIX shells; in Windows, probably, better switch to PowerShell which has [native colored output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.3) instead of outputting ANSI codes by hand.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 LTSC 1909 version

Comment: How are you defining the ESC variable?

Answer (score 0):

To color a string in a Batch file, you can try adding

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
```

at the **very** top of your batch script, and then

```
:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
```

at the **very** bottom of it (or you can also make a separate .bat file that you will call).

Then, you can print any text using:

```
call :colorEcho 0c "Hi, I'm red"
```

> ***NOTE**: Special characters are not "patched" yet (you cannot print them). I'll find a way to patch them.*

You can print the result of the command this way:

```
for /f %%i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (
    call :colorEcho 0c "%%i" 
    set result=%%i
)
```

Lemme know if you're good with it! :)

Comment: I followed your advice to color the output but it showed error " findstr : Argument missing after /a       (See my question revision). Also it extracted two MAC addresses - one is connected and the other is disconnected. how to achieve the connected MAC address only)

Comment: @VB88 found the problem.
There was no kind of issue with the command itself: the "findstr : Argument missing after /a" error is displayed just because you didn't put an `exit` command after the `for` loop.
This way, after exiting the loop, the batch file will not stop, entering the :colorEcho subroutine, but since it hasn't been called with the arguments for the color and for the text to display, it simply tells you "hey, I haven't been invoked with the right arguments". Try putting a little `exit` after the `for` loop.
(for the MAC address: I have no clue how to get only the connected one)

Comment: I searched and found a script which can find the active connected MAC address. I tried to add your script to make the output in color but it shows error (see my REVISION 3). Please help to see where should be modified to make to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```bash
@echo off 

for /f skip^=4 %%a in ('"echo;prompt;$E|%ComSpec%"
    ')do for /f skip^=3 %%G in ('"%__AppDir__%getmac.exe"
    ')do echo/%%~a[31m%%~G %%~a[0;m && set "_result=%%~G"
```

---

[image]

- In a double for loop:

```bash
@echo off 

for /f skip^=4 %%a in ('echo;prompt;$E^|%ComSpec%"'
    )do set "_esq=%%~a"

for /f skip^=3 %%G in ('"%__AppDir__%getmac.exe"')do =;(
     echo/%_esq%[31m%%~G%_esq%[0m && set "_result=%%~G" );=
```

---

> // Edit refer: ***REVISION 3***

[image]

```bash
echo off 

for %%i in (NetConnectionID,ProductName,MacAddress,Index,IPSubNet,IPAddress)do set "_%%~i="

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^> %%G in (
    `wmic nic where netenabled^='true' get netconnectionid^,productname^,macaddress^,index /format:xml ^| find "VALUE&" ^| sort /r`
    )do if not defined _netconnectionid =;(
         set "_netconnectionid=%%~G"
        )else if not defined _productname =;(
         set "_productname=%%~G"
        )else if not defined _macaddress =;(
         set "_macaddress=%%~G"
        )else for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^> %%i in =;(
            `wmic nicconfig where index^='%%~G' get ipsubnet^,ipaddress /format:xml ^| find "VALUE&" ^| findstr "[1-9].\." ^| sort /r`
            )do if not defined _ipsubnet =;(set "_index=%%~G" && set "_ipsubnet=%%~i")else set "_ipaddress=%%~i"
                 
for /f skip^=4 %%a in ('echo;prompt;$E^|%ComSpec%')do for %%G in =;(
     NetConnectionID,MacAddress,IPAddress,IPSubNet,Index
    )do if "%%~G" == "NetConnectionID" =;(
         %ComSpec% /v /e /c "echo/%%~a[33;4m%%~G:%%~a[0;m %%~a[93m!_%%~G! %%~a[0;m"
        )else if "%%~G" == "MacAddress" =;(
         %ComSpec% /v /e /c "echo/     %%~a[33;4m%%~G:%%~a[0;m %%~a[93m!_%%~G! %%~a[0;m"
        )else if "%%~G" == "IPAddress" =;(
         %ComSpec% /v /e /c "echo/      %%~a[33;4m%%~G:%%~a[0;m %%~a[93m!_%%~G! %%~a[0;m"
        )else if "%%~G" == "IPSubNet" =;(
         %ComSpec% /v /e /c "echo/       %%~a[33;4m%%~G:%%~a[0;m %%~a[93m!_%%~G! %%~a[0;m"
        )else %ComSpec% /v /e /c "echo/          %%~a[33;4m%%~G:%%~a[0;m %%~a[93m!_%%~G! %%~a[0;m"
```

---

## **[Use ANSI colors in the terminal](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-ansi.html)**

## [image]

---

## Some references using ansi code strings

**[ANSI Escape Sequences](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)**

**[`Tetris.BAT`](https://github.com/Honguito98/batch-game-flappy-bird/blob/master/Flappy_Bird.bat)** by **[@Aacini](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6812)**

- **[Tetris game in a pure Batch file](https://github.com/Honguito98/batch-game-flappy-bird/blob/master/Flappy_Bird.bat)**

**[`Flappy_Bird.bat`](https://github.com/yutsunoki/Flappy_Bird_With_Batch_File)**

- **[Using ANSI Code in game in bat file](https://github.com/yutsunoki/Flappy_Bird_With_Batch_File)**

**[`Pacman_kinda.bat`](https://github.com/IcarusLivesHF/Batch-Script-Projects/blob/main/Pacman_kinda.bat)**

- **[Another sample fo Using ANSI Code in game in bat file](https://github.com/IcarusLivesHF/Batch-Script-Projects/blob/main/Pacman_kinda.bat)**

**[`Library.bat` Revision 4.1.0](https://github.com/IcarusLivesHF/Windows-Batch-Library/blob/8812670566744d2ee14a9a68a06be333a27488cc/Library.bat)**

- **[The Window Batch Library // Documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IcarusLivesHF/Windows-Batch-Library/master/documentation.bat)**

**[Search for *"Bat Games"*](https://www.dostips.com/forum/search.php?keywords=games)** on **[DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/)**

- **[Many examples using **ANSI Codes**](https://www.dostips.com/forum/search.php?keywords=games)**